# Is it possible to build 64-bit dll on Windows with GHC?

Tags: haskell, dll, 64-bit, ghc

What I am looking for is exporting my haskell module as a 64-bit dll. My setup is 64-bit Windows 7 and Haskell Platform 2013.2.0.0.

I tried building with `ghc --make -static -shared -fPIC ff.hs -o ff_dll.dll` which works fine except for it produces 32-bit version (I managed to call it from another app).

So my question is: is it possible to build 64-bit dll with GHC on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a 64-bit GHC from [the official GHC website's download section](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_8_2#windows64). You can then `cabal install haskell-platform` to build the libraries that normally ship with the Platform.

Comment: great, that worked, thanks a lot. Follow-up question: if I ever happen to need building a 32-bit dll, would it be possible to use 64-bit GHC for that purpose (adding some extra flags maybe) or I just use a different version of GHC?

Comment: @ArtemSolod I do not believe GHC has any cross-compiling capability at all yet, though there were some whispers a while back about making it happen in the future.

Comment: The solution doesn't work anymore - `cabal` doesn't find `haskell-platform` package.