# Dynamic versions of 64 bit base libraries for GHC on Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, dll, 64-bit

Current binary GHC distribution (7.8.2) doesn't have dynamic base libraries (`base` proper, `ghc-prim` etc). So it's not possible to use dynamic linking. (It's possible to produce a statically linked dll of course). So [an older solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23244910/805266) is outdated.

What is the easiest way to get 64-bit dynamic linking on Windows with 7.8.x?

Comment: I'm slighly confused about your question though, the SO question you link to is about producing a dynamic haskell library. This is still stupported. Everything is just statically linked into the library.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the issue is serious, and neither 7.8 nor 7.10 have dynamic linking on Windows.

The problem is that with more features added to GHC some of GHC DLLs started to export more than 64k symbols. Which is impossible on Windows as 64k is an inherent limit of Windows dynamic linking.

So authors of GHC should rewrite it so it exports less symbols. Few solutions are outlined in the GHC bug tracker (one of them is splitting a big DLL into few smaller ones). But as far as I know nobody is working on this issue at the moment.

Comment: I'm currenly working on it, but a bit short on time so can't promise for 8.2.x but certainly one of the 8.x releases. Progress can be tracked https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5987 here

Comment: @Phyx What is the current status? The issue 5987 is closed now, but can I build dynamic base libs on Windows?